# Stack Overflow: Friends and question precomments

Tags: feature-request, linkedin

Today an idea came to me. What if we could have **Friends** in Stack Overflow (like the relations in LinkedIn). And when we would post a question they would be the first ones to know. If we have misspellings or syntax errors in our questions they will be the first ones to see them and they would inform us, or they could help us correct them.

Comment: It looks like facebook feature...

Comment: Spellcheck is your friend. :-)

Comment: I got enough social networks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I doubt this **Q&A engine** will turn into a **social network**

Comment: Are we all that socially defect? ;-)

Comment: Social network (noun): Software whose "users" table has a many-to-many relationship with itself. a) *"I just love adding new records to the UserUser table in my social network!"* b) *"Your worth as a human being is measured by your number of (Twitter followers|Facebook friends|MySpace friends|Youtube subscribers)!"*

Comment: @Ivo, There are many social networking tools and sites already available. Why dilute StackOverflow?

Comment: Stackoverflow **IS** a Social Network. Ask a question, provide an answer, or submit a comment and you'll demonstrate my point.

Comment: @Welbog: What is this MySpace you speak of?

Answer (score 5):

I don't see how this makes particularly good sense.  It's much better if the question is brought before the entire community to edit and improve.  If you want to follow someone, each user's page offers an RSS feed.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't make sense at all. This goes under the assumption that your friends are going to be the ones who want to clean up after you after you make a mess of yourself, which is patently false (you don't even know if your friends are smart enough to clean up after you to begin with).

Like Juan said, every attempt so far at turning Stack Overflow into a social networking engine has been shot down and for plenty of good reasons.

Comment: While I disagree with this feature-request, Stackoverflow IS a social network :) Apparently many just want it to not become too social-network-icky.

Comment: That's taking an awfully broad definition of a social network that isn't really at all related to the technical definition of a social networking website in the web world.

Answer (score 0):

I like the idea of unidirectional relationships, i.e. the ability for me to mark people who appear, to me, to be competent, keen or open-minded.

The SO scores, whilst useful, are not always descriptive as someone making relatively few brilliant answers, someone making a large number of mediocre answers and someone who happens to place a good answer on a very popular question could all end up with a very similar score.

I would like the ability to record people I see around who make good answers or questions. This could be a simple 'Remember this peep' button or, better still, a `+1 this peep` button. Whilst not 'friends' in the conventional sense this would still allow me record my prejudices :)